# Python zero out the value if previous indicator R exist

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a data sets as follow:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Stat': ['Bad', 'Bad', 'Good', 'Good', 'Good', 'Good' ], 'Quantity': ['1', '1', '4', '5', '2', '1']})
```

If "Bad" exist, then the next "Good" should be 0. The number of times "Bad" appear should be equal to the number "Good" that is zero-ed.
Expected output is as below:

```
Stat Quantity
Bad  1
Bad  1
Good 0
Good 0
Good 2
Good 1
```

Of course "Bad" is not always there, sometimes the data don't have "Bad"
I use "heavy" if-else statement in Excel to make this work..
I am trying to use Python to kind of improve this.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: If it were `[Bad Bad Good Bad Good Good]` would the final `Good` still get zeroed out because there were 3 total Bad's before it?

Comment: Do you mean if Bad, look back and count the Bads and Change equal number of good to zero?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming there is only two choices (here good or bad), you can do it by creating a mask where the value is good with `eq`. Then with `cumsum` you want to know where the number of good up to a row is less than the number of bad up to this row, also calculated with `cumsum` but with the opposite `~` of the mask for good, then ensure that the rows meeting this condition above is also a row with good with `&`. Finally use `loc` to set the value to 0:

```
# mask of good
mask_good = df['Stat'].eq('Good')
# mask of row to be zeroed
mask_zero = mask_good.cumsum().le((~mask_good).cumsum())& mask_good
# assign the value
df.loc[mask_zero, 'Quantity'] = 0

print (df)
   Stat Quantity
0   Bad        1
1   Bad        1
2  Good        0
3  Good        0
4  Good        2
5  Good        1
```

Edit: as pointed out by @Quang in the comment, this method does not work with

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Stat': ['Bad']*2 + ['Good']*4 + ['Bad']*2 + ['Good']*3, 
                   'Quantity': np.arange(1,12)})
```

here is an alternative by using for and a variable incremented when bad and decreased only if positive:

```
nb_bad = 0
mask_zero = np.zeros_like(df['Stat'])
for i, b in enumerate(df['Stat'].eq('Bad').to_numpy()):
    if b:
        nb_bad += 1
    elif nb_bad>0:
        nb_bad -= 1
        mask_zero[i] = 1

# then loc the same way than above
df.loc[mask_zero, 'Quantity'] = 0
```

Comment: @QuangHoang what do you mean one block only?

Comment: Try your code with `df = pd.DataFrame({'Stat': ['Bad']*2 + ['Good']*4 + ['Bad']*2 + ['Good', 'Good', 'Good' ], 
                   'Quantity': np.arange(1,12)})`.

Comment: Can if the data source is an excel, will the above still work? It seems that it is not..or maybe  made a mistake...I use df = pd.read_excel()...

Comment: @Hakumaru so I guess the problem was more what QuangHoang pointed out, see my edit it should work

Comment: Hi, I use the new code but i am getting this error" 'Series' object has no attribute 'to_numpy'

Comment: @Hakumaru you are using an older version of pandas, it is new since version 0.24. so you can replace with values like  `for i, b in enumerate(df['Stat'].eq('Bad').values):`

Comment: Brilliant. I upgrade my pandas version. The error is now gone. BUT i am getting Bad as 0.

Comment: @Hakumaru it is not supposed to to select any rows with 'Bad', so I see two things: the first idea is that it was 0 before the process, the second possiibility is that it is not exactly Bad, if it is BAD (case sensitive) for example or 'Bad ' (with a whitespace) then it fails, could you elaborate?